# Add .jar SDK to Cordova Hybrid app Visual Studio

Tags: android, cordova, jar, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to implement an SDK for my Handheld API to an Cordova Hybrid App in Visual Studio. It's a `.jar` File.
I'm new in Cordova/PhoneGap developing, so I just want to know if its possible to generate the Bindings API/Wrapper automatically like in Xamarin with "`Bindings Library(Android)`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I just want to know if its possible to generate the Bindings API/Wrapper automatically like in Xamarin with "Bindings Library(Android)".

As far as I know, there is no way to generate the Bindings API/Wrapper automatically. If you want to call the APIs in your `.jar` file, you can use the [Ace Plugin](http://microsoft.github.io/ace/docs/native-code/) to invoke the native codes.

Or you can write a plugin that reference this framework(using `<lib-file />` tag in `Plugin.xml`), and wrap the API manually with JS code.

For details about creating an Android Plugin, please refer to [Android Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html).